# Scala play evolutions are applying duplicately

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-evolutions

i am using Scala play evolutions and have this in application.conf

```
evolutionplugin=enabled
applyEvolutions.default=true
applyDownEvolutions.default=true
```

Also i have this sql script in one evolution

```
ALTER TABLE `User` ADD `Level` INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
```

However when i start Play2 in PROD mode i always get this error

```
Duplicate column name 'Level' [ERROR:1060, SQLSTATE:42S21]
```

When i check database before starting app play_evolutions row has state "applied" on corrensponding script, but after starting up , it changes to "applying_up" , it looks like that evolutions are starting over and over everytime. How can i apply only "new" evolutions and not applying every evolution from start? Now its pain in the ass because when i add new column to table i also need to have "down" script to first drop that column and "up" script to add this column, but this leads to dropping also all data on that column in production database. Am i missing something with evolutions? (For me "evolution" should only continue when it ended last time not everytime from scratch).

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you might have changed already applied evolutions sql. So, it might be going down to the changed step and auto applying up. Also the evolution steps must be exactly opposite to each other. Otherwise you can never reach the exact database state.

In production you should disable `applyDownEvolutions.default=true`. Otherwise as you said you might loose the data

Comment: I thought that too , but i cleaned whole database to have no tables, started application , stopped, and again started and then it fails, also when i check new hash and old hash on corrensponding evolutions its same. So no changes in files are made just restarting app and it fails.